# jQuery .show() not working as intended. hides well but does not show

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this, after the user clicks on the `.item_list` it shows what it should, if they click `.upload_items li` it doesn't do anything. I am very lost as to why. here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7oxrpcyw/1/) with more details. too much html to post here

```
  $('.upload_items').hide(); 
  $('.item-list').click(function() {        
    $(".upload_items").slideDown();    
    $('#node_project_form_group_document').show();
    $('#edit-field-video').hide();
    $('#edit-field-images-upload').hide();
  });
  $('.upload_items').children('li').eq(1).click(function () {
    $('#node_project_form_group_document').show();
  });
```

Comment: DOM manipulation can generally only be done from the ready event handler or after. Wrap your code in `$(function() { /* code here */ });` and try again.

Comment: your fiddle has errors

Comment: Edited, sorry about that :/

Comment: I think it is doing its job well, clicked on the video `li` in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7oxrpcyw/4/ and said 'console'. Why do you want to `show` the same thing  as far as I can see, it is already `.show`ed when I clicked on the item_list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - so the html you provided in the fiddle is really excessive, so instead of going through the whole thing, I created a very simple example to show/hide sections using jQuery's `toggle()` function, which I would recommend for this scenario since it automatically detects the target element's current visible state.  Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/Lv1wwfp2/2/

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="clickable" data-id="1">Group 1</li>
        <li class="clickable" data-id="2">Group 2</li>
        <li class="clickable" data-id="3">Group 3</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="Group1">Group 1</div>
    <div id="Group2">Group 2</div>
    <div id="Group3">Group 3</div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("div").hide();
            $(".clickable").click(function () {
                var id = $(this).data("id");
                $("#Group" + id).toggle();

            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that's pretty knarly looking. Instead of .children('li').eq(1), try using CSS instead.

```
$(".upload_items li:nth-of-type(1)").click();
```

Comment: I had an alert there and it works fine. Why use this instead?

Comment: Personal preference I suppose. Why use JS when simple CSS will suffice?